# Jquery.Ajax not posting to PHP. Php returns nothing for $_POST[]

Tags: php, html, ajax, drag-and-drop

So I've got this small draggable item that I am able to drag and drop in the canvas I've created and that is working perfectly fine, however as I want to save the position of the draggable item when the item is dropped, I am using ajax to post to PHP where PHP will then store it in sessions.
However it is simply not posting. No error shows. The $_POST[] simply returns nothing.

Notice I have set value of the ajax data to 1. I am hardcoding atm for testing purpose.

**page-online-tool.php**

```
<div id="Canvas" class="col-xs-6">

    <div class="col-xs-11" id="Purse_Background"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-1">

        <div id="FLOWER_Blue" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
            <img src="imgs/blue_01.png" alt=""/>
        </div>

        <p id="pos_T" ></p>
        <p id="pos_R" ></p>
        <p id="pos_B" ></p>
        <p id="pos_L" ></p>

        <input type="text" id="id_input_01" name="name_input_01" value=""/>

        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['Blue_Top_Position'])) {  
            $Blue_Top_Position = $_POST['Blue_Top_Position'];
            echo $Blue_Top_Position;
        } else {
            echo 'fail';    
        }

        ?>

    </div>

</div>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

**JQUERY.JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#FLOWER_Blue').draggable({

    containment: "#Canvas",
    scroll: false,

    drag: function(event, ui){

        $BLUE_T = ui.position.top;
        $BLUE_R = ui.position.right;
        $BLUE_B = ui.position.bottom;
        $BLUE_L = ui.position.left;

        $('#pos_T').text('TOP: ' + $BLUE_T);
        $('#pos_R').text('RIGHT: ' + $BLUE_R);
        $('#pos_B').text('BOTTOM: ' + $BLUE_B);
        $('#pos_L').text('LEFT: ' + $BLUE_L);


        $('#id_input_01').val(ui.position.top)

    },

    stop: function(event, ui){

       $.ajax({    
        url:'http://localhost/42_TEST/page-online-tool.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {Blue_Top_Position : 1},
        done: function(data) {
            console.log('done');
        }
    }).fail (function() {
        alert('error');
    })   

}

}

);

});
```

Comment: The data that's being posted to the server, can you see it in your console? I am using Google Chrome to capture the AJAX requests to see what's being send and received to and from the server. This is a build-in feature.

Comment: You're setting your data in the wrong `json` format. It should be `{'Blue_Top_Position' : 1}` with the `''`, else that value won't be anything, also make sure your `url` is correct. Else nothing will be send through either way.

Comment: Nothing shows in my console & I've also amended and added the '' to my data object name, same result

Comment: I've amended the code so now dataType is text. And on 'success' I console.log the data. My console.log is showing the entire html of the php url with the exact result I want. However what I want is for the php page to have this view, not just have it in my console as HTML data

Comment: $.ajax({    
            url:'http://localhost/42_TEST/page-online-tool.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {Blue_Top_Position: 1},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }).fail (function() {
            alert('error');
        })